# Working Angularjs template cache on build and deployment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, gruntjs

I am developing angular directives that used html template.

```
angular.module("app")
       .directive("ticket", [function(){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                templateUrl: "app/ticket/ticket.html"
             }
        }])
```

This directive is working and I can change ticket.html content and run application to see changes.

But I read about $templateCache method to increase performance of big projects. And I can use [grunt-angular-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) to create all of template cache.

But I need to change my directive.

```
angular.module("app")
       .directive("ticket", ["$templateCache",function($templateCache){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                template: $templateCache.get("app/ticket/ticket.html")
             }
        }])
```

Can I separate the build and deployment usage of template.

- `templateUrl: "app/ticket/ticket.html"`
- `template: $templateCache.get("app/ticket/ticket.html")`

I will select one of that ways. What is the professional approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to update this, you will automatically get it from the cache if you leave your code as it is, here you are just passing a template path to angular and angular gets it for you from the cache. `$templateCache.get("app/ticket/ticket.html")` is only needed if you want to load a template via js.